# Symbolizing verbal statement into propositional logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Suppose that individuals and predicates are defined as follows:

- S: should be shunned
- U: is prone to unruly behavior,
- J: is a friend of Josh
- M: is a friend of mine
- d: Daniella
- e: Erika

Symbolize the following:
 1. Daniella is a friend of Josh and Erika is a friend of mine.

My answer: $$dJ\land eM$$

2. Some of Josh's friend are prone to unruly behavior.

My answer: $$\text{Some of Josh's friend}U \qquad \text{(pretty sure this is wrong)}$$

3. If Daniella is a friend of Josh then she is prone to unruly behavior and should be shunned.

My answer:  $$dJ\implies U\land S$$

Comment: What textbook are you using? To have objects and predicates on them is first-order logic, not propositional logic anymore. Predicates are always put before the object like $J(d)$ to say that $d$ satisfies $J$, not after as in English. "$U$" by itself makes no sense; $U(what)$?

Comment: i apologize for this. I'll try to clear things out.

Comment: edited it. hope you guys understand it better. Appreciate all the help i can get :)

Comment: So I assume $S,U,J,M$ are relational symbols and $d, e$ are constant symbols, right?! So you want to translate to predicate logic?!

Comment: yes, sorry if i'm clueless.

Comment: are my answers incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #$1$ I would use $J(d) \wedge M(e)$.

For #$2$ I would use $\exists x:J(x) \wedge U(x)$.

For #$3$ I would use $J(d) \implies U(d) \wedge S(d)$.

Comment: Thank you so much :) May you please explain how you arrived those answers?

Comment: @JaneDoe: You're welcome. I translated them from English to propositional logic. I'm not sure how else I can explain translation from one language to another.

Comment: do you think my answers can be considered correct?

Comment: @JaneDoe: I think that your 1st and 3rd answers were mostly correct (except for the syntax).

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: @JaneDoe:You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If I take it right, you mean:

- $U(x)$ means "$x$ is prone to unruly behaviour";
- $S(x)$ means "$x$ should be shunned";
- $J(x)$ means "$x$ is a friend of Josh";
- $M(x)$ means "$x$ is a friend of mine";
- $d$ represents Daniella;
- $e$ represents Erika.

Assuming this is true, I would give the following representations:

1. "Daniella is a friend of Josh and Erika is a friend of mine":

   $$J(d)\land M(e).$$
2. "Some of Josh's friends are prone to unruly behaviour":

   $$\exists x:J(x)\land U(x).$$
3. "If Daniella is a friend of Josh, then she is prone to unruly behaviour and should be shunned":

   $$J(d)\implies U(d)\land S(d).$$

Remarks:

- As @user21820 pointed out [in his comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679702/symbolizing-verbal-statement-into-propositional-logic#comment3427771_1679702), you write $U(x)$, not $xU$, to mean "$x$ satisfies $U$";
- "Some of Josh's friends etc" is equivalent to "There exists a friend of Josh who etc", hence your attempt, which should have been $U(\text{Some of Josh's friends})$, is better as $\exists x:J(x)\land U(x)$;
- You wrote $U$ and $S$ by themselves you your third answer, probably forgetting $d$; that, of course, doesn't make sense, because you are making a phrase without a subject;
- [Please learn MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your attempts properly; also, notice that linebreaking is not respected by Markdown, so to get a linebreak you need an empty line, not just a change of line in the Markdown.

Comment: Thank you for your help and I'm sorry for my format.